# From annualized Sharpe Ratio to number of daily losses

Tags: portfolio-management, risk-management, sharpe-ratio

I have seen a few statements that link a particular annualised Sharpe Ratio to the likely frequency of 'loss day' across a given period:

*e.g. "A annualised Sharpe Ratio of X, implies the portfolio would suffer a down day Y times a month."*

What are the steps to go from a given Sharpe Ratio to the likely number of loss days in a given period?

Comment: You have the mean and the standard deviation. You could assume normality of returns (or something else) or apply Chebyshev.

Comment: @BobJansen and if I make an assumption of normality of returns, what are the steps from there?